# What is an upside-down matrix called?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Say we have an $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{i,j=1,...,n}$. In relation to $A$, (1) does the upside-down matrix $A^\cap:=[a_{n+1-i,j}]_{i,j=1,...,n}$ have a name, and (2) does it have any nice matrix-algebraic properties?

Clearly $A^\cap$ is singular iff $A$ is; but are there any other relationships? Consideration of simple cases shows the eigenvalues to be quite different.

Comment: Hmm likely a product of [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) and $A$?

Comment: Also, $A^\cap= SA$, where $S$ is the permutation matrix corresponding to permutation $(n\dots 1)$.

Comment: You could investigate whether  $(A+B)^\cap = A^\cap + B^\cap$ and $(AB)^\cap = A^\cap\;B^\cap$ and so on.

Comment: @GEdgar : The first is true, but the second needs modifying to $(AB)^\cap=A^\cap B$.

Comment: What motivates this question?  Why do you consider these upside down matrices?  What makes you think that they *deserve* to have a special name?  Is there anything which you can do to provide some extra context?  Lacking such context, "Sally" seems like a good name, though "Ruth" could work, too,

Comment: @XanderHenderson :  From the question, it is clear that I do not know whether they have any interesting properties. If none are known, then they do not deserve to have a special name, and we can all happily forget about them.

Comment: @JohnBentin But *you* brought up this matrix operation.  Since you brought it up, surely there was a reason for it, no?  What motivates this question?  *Why* do you consider these upside down matrices?  Again, please edit the question to add some context.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : Just idle curiosity. There is a Matlab operation flipud($\cdot$) which does this for computer output—presumably for the purpose of display only. I happened to wonder whether this had any nontrivial *mathematical* properties (see my second paragraph), but I couldn't find anything about this on the internet, first because I didn't have a name for it—and perhaps, more fundamentally, because there isn't anything, and maybe deservedly so.